# Mod_rewrite for url with?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I can't find my answer on the other questions here in StackOverflow.. 
mod_rewrites generator are failing so I don't know how to do that..

I have that urls: http://example.com/?index&category=football

football are dynamic generator by php, so there is many categories.
So I want my URL like this: http://example.com/football

How to do that with mod_rewrite?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you post your mod_rewrite code(.htaccess file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \ /+\?index&category=([^&\ ]+)
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ /?index&category=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /index.php?category=$1
    #RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /index.php?category=$1
```

Answer (score 0):

This should makes URL http://example.com/football works as if http://example.com/?index&category=football was used:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^/?([^/$]*) /?index&category=$1 [L]
```

Lines 2 to 5 (from `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s` to `RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]`) are optional: they makes any existing file named as a category name (eg. *football*) be served directly (not using */?index&category=...*).